# how to replace word that contains only special characters from string using regular expression

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a string and I need to search and replace such a words that contain only special characters in it.  no, any other letter 
e.g( @@#$$ , %^&%%$ , &(){}":?? ).

Comment: are you want replace it in string?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.
Post a sample of your code, show us your effort

Comment: Please, show some test cases, your code, what you get and what you're expecting

Comment: I'm not sure if he wants to search those words and bring them up or just search those words and replace them with `??`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that "words" that only contain special characters are chunks of non-whitespace symbols that are not word characters (letters/digits/underscore).

That means you may split the string with whitespaces (with `preg_split('~\s+~', $s)`), get rid of all chunks that only consist of non-word chars (with `preg_grep('~^\W+$~', $arr, PREG_GREP_INVERT)`), and then join the chunks with a space:

```
$s = "''' Dec 2016, ?!$%^ End '''";
$result = implode(" ", preg_grep('~^\W+$~', preg_split('~\s+~', $s), PREG_GREP_INVERT));
echo $result;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/PGzymS)

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor Stribiżew this is realy work for me.  this is good solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Function**

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
}
```

**Usage:**

```
echo clean('a|"bc!@£de^&$f g');
```

[code link](https://eval.in/704540)

Comment: Not sure it answer the question. OP said there is a string with word**s** and some of them contain **only** special characters.